# how to make log files to be generated at the same location as jar file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j2, jsch

I am using jsch channelexec to call .sh file. The content of .sh file is,

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar /xxx/yyy.war
```

In my log file, I mentioned the path as

> ./logs/xxx.log

when I run the ap in intellij, I could see the log files to be in the same folder as the project.
When I run the app from terminal using java -jar /xxx/yyy/war the log files are in the same location as the jar file.

But when I try to call the .sh file using jsch inside java, the app started running but the log files does not appear anywhere. Not sure whether they are created or the location where they are created. How to make it appear in the same location as the .sh file while using jsch in java to execute the .sh file, springboot, gradle?

I am using ubuntu, log4j2, intellij, java, and jsch.

Answer (score 0):

Your log files are probably under the home directory for your user. Run a fresh jsck and type `pwd` - they might be there.

Really with log files however you should fully specify the path. Either via a fixed location, e.g. `/opt/app/logs/xxx.log`, or via a symlink from a fixed location, or via a system environment variable that you *know* is always going to be set, e.g. `$LOGS_HOME/xxx.log`

Relying on `./` is a really bad idea, since it completely depends on the execution context.